# Displaying data with AngularJS loaded by NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building my first MEAN twitter like application and currently try to display a list of posts to the gui. what I currently do is:

**The angular.js part:**

in my `main.js`:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Feed', function($scope, Feed) {
        $scope.feeds = Feed.showFeeds();
// ... 
}
```

in my `feed.js`:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Feed', ['$http', '$location', '$rootScope', '$cookieStore', '$alert', '$resource',
        function ($http, $location, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $alert, $resource) {
    return {
      // other functions like addFeed: function(f) {...},
      showFeeds: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/feeds');
      }
```

**The node.js part:**

```
app.get('/api/feeds', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = Feed.find();
    query.limit(8);
    query.exec(function (err, feeds) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(feeds)
        // feeds is a corret JSON with all my data at this point
    });
});
```

and my `home.html`:

```
 <p>{{ feeds }}</p> <!-- for testing - this just returns {} -->
 <div ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
 <div>
     <a href="/feeds/{{feed._id}}">{{feed.feedMessage}}</a>
 </div>
```

So my problem is: Everything loads fine, but nothing renders out on the page, I don't get any errors, just my `$scope.feeds` object is empty. I'm pretty new to this, so maybe it's an obvious bug, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Does your get request return any data? You can open the developer tools to see.

Comment: yes, I currently log the json out to my console after `res.send(feeds)`. It filled with the correct items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are returning a promise, and you need to be accessing the data.:

```
Feed.showFeeds().success( function(data) { 

    $scope.feeds = data.feeds;

});
```

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately `data.feeds` returns `undefined` even though on the node side `res.send(feeds)` clearly sends data.

Comment: feeds probably isn't the right key. I'm not sure how your JSON is structured but if you change your node return to: `res.send( { feeds: feeds} )` it should work

Answer (score 2):

The '$http' service provided by angular return always an instance of '$q', another angular service which allows us to use the *Promise* syntax for all async commands.

When you assign the return of `Feed.showFeeds()` to your scope variable, you bind a promise to your view and Angular can't display it.

You should use the success method provide by `$http` in order to get the server data and bind them to your scope variable like **bencripps** said.

Note: The success method (and error) are specific methods of `$http` and call the `$digest` [method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) of angular which triggers a refresh of the view automatically.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Feed', function($scope, Feed) {
        $scope.feeds = [];
        Feed.showFeeds().success(function(data) { 
           //depends of the json return 
           //try a console.log(data)
           $scope.feeds = data.feeds
        });

// ... 
}
```